# Open YouTube App diectly in VR 360 Split mode

Tags: java, android, youtube, 360-virtual-reality

I want to open a 360 video Directy in Split Mode in YouTube App on a button click. Read a lot of tutorials but nothing shows such thing but a few apps are already doing it like this one: 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ekm.youtubevr3dvideos

Does anyone one know what is the right way to open videos in 360 mode.?

Comment: Your link is not working.

Comment: Not possible right now, as they said.  https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/FPZvA0fDZt0